# SpecFlow scenario exclusion

Tags: specflow, xunit

I would like all my scenarios to run, but I'd like to tag some scenarios so they are only excluded when running in certain environments. For example, when a scenario has no tags I want it to run in all environments, but if I tag it with `@dev` I want it to be excluded from all non-dev environments.

Is there a way to use scope binding to achieve this or is it better implemented with execution flags on the test runner?

Other than flags passed to the test runner, I was thinking maybe a scenario hook would be possible, but not sure how to implement the exclude condition because once the scenario has started I can't find a way to abort it.

Comment: Which test runner are you using? SpecFlow+Runner, XUnit, NUnit, MSTest, ...?

Comment: Just edited the tags: xUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using xUnit, Tags are translated into Traits.
With them, you can filter which scenarios you want to execute.

This runs all tests with the @dev tag:

> xunit.console.exe ... -trait "Category=dev"

Brendan Connolly wrote a nice blog post about xUnit traits: http://www.brendanconnolly.net/organizing-tests-with-xunit-traits/

About aborting an already started scenario: This is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I am already well versed with passing tags/traits on the command line but was hoping the second part of your answer would be a Yes ;) ...unless there is a way of building a hook to filter scenarios without passing tags excess tags on the cl.